# An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near [BEGIN]

Tags: sql-server-2012

I got this message, can ya help me?

> Msg 4145, Level 15, State 1, Procedure insert_customer, Line 7 [Batch Start Line 822]
> An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'BEGIN'.

My code:

```
CREATE TRIGGER insert_customer ON customers
FOR INSERT
AS
DECLARE @customer_id AS VARCHAR(25)
SELECT @customer_id-customer_id FROM inserted
IF @@ERROR -0
BEGIN
PRINT 'Data ' + @customer_id + 'Berhasil dimasukkan ke tabel customer.'
END
```

Comment: it is a typo error. You have use the `-` instead of `=` on both places. (1) `@customer_id-customer_id` and (2) `IF @@ERROR -0`

Comment: Other that that, your trigger will not work properly. You are assuming `inserted` only contains `1 row` which in actual fact may be `0` or `N` rows.